# Given I am living in Iraq, where do I apply for an Irish visa?

Tags: visas, ireland, iraqi-citizens

I am an Iraqi doctor and I have a job offer in Ireland.

Given I am living in Iraq, where do I apply for an Irish visa?

Comment: [Online at the Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Apply%20for%20a%20visa) and, should you need it, the [home page for the site](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply online via the website for the [Irish Naturalisation and Immigration Service](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Apply%20for%20a%20visa).

Importantly, [visa decisions are released every Tuesday](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visa%20Decisions) and published on the site (without revealing any personal details).

As a caution, there is an [alert of an email fraud](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/visas-updates#2) that asks for money. You do not have to pay for an 'International Employment Eligibility Clearance and Security Bond' to get a job in Ireland.